# Защита от дурака

Tags: c++

```
while (cin.fail() || (N < 1 || N > 5))
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    cout << "Error, try again " << endl;
    cin >> N;
}
```

Пусть есть такой кусок кода. Нужно, чтобы если при вводе копируется и вставляется куча любого текста, он после каждой строки текста не выдавал ошибку, а выдал после всего, либо вовсе как-то запретить вставлять в консоль(но только сделать это программно). Просто обрывать работу проги - не пойдет

Comment: Честно, ваш вопрос сформулирован довольно-таки расплывчато. Опишите более подробно, что ваша программа должна делать, какие вводные данные поступают, каким должен быть вывод программы, приведите пару примеров ввода и вывода.

Comment: программа достаточно примитивная, в этом куске мне нужно задать размерность массива. Если я скопирую и вставлю, например, кусок того же кода, то после окончания каждой строки будет сообщение об ошибке. Мне нужно, чтобы сообщение об ошибке высвечивалось один раз

Answer (score 1):

Вам не что-то такое нужно?

```
int inputInt(const char * prompt, int m = INT_MIN, int M = INT_MAX)
{
    int N;
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << prompt << " (целое от " << m << " до " << M << "): " << std::flush;
        if ((std::cin >> N).good() && (m <= N) && (N <= M)) return N;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите.\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Число вне допустимого диапазона значений. Повторите ввод.\n";
        }
        std::cin.ignore(100,'\n');
    }
}

a = inputInt("Введите размер массива",1,10);
```

Comment: нет, нужно, чтобы если при вводе копируется и вставляется куча, выдал после всего...:))